# How can I extract a number of rows from a very big file from a known position?

Tags: grep, xml

I have a huge .xml file that weights 500Mb and I want to extract some text from it starting from a known position that I can grep.

When I just do grep it shows me where the keyword occurs, but it does not show me the row number. What if I need to extract 200 rows from the first grep?

Comment: Use something like `xmlstarlet` and XPath to pick out the elements, attributes, or values that you need. Provide the keys that define the required items and someone will give you the proper answer.

Comment: Better add sample input/expected input. grep is not the way to go here

Comment: grep is line based xml is not (use an xml processing tool). Also you question is not clear: we would need some example data. inputs and outputs. And for you to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract lines range using `awk`.
The following command will extract 2-6 lines (inclusive) from FILENAME and write it to the OUTPUT.

```bsh
cat FILENAME | awk 'NR >= 2 && NR <= 6' > OUTPUT
```

You can also make it extract from a known position til the end of file like this

```bsh
cat FILENAME | awk 'NR >= 2' > OUTPUT
```

`NR` stands for "Number Record"

You can also get the line number dynamically using grep and pass it to the `awk` command to extract the those lines

```bsh
LINE_START=`grep -nr "STRING" FILENAME | grep -o '^[0-9]\+'`
cat FILENAME | awk 'NR >= $LINE_START' > OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep -A200 searchword file.xml` can be used for listing 200 lines after each match. `searchword` is the word you are searching for and `file.xml` is the XML filename.

You can also use `-B200` to list 200 lines before each match and `-C200` to list 200 lines before and 200 lines after.

Note that a proper XML parser is almost always a better choice than using grep or a regexp:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/131264

Answer (score -1):

In fact I can easily open it using Notepad++ and then just ctrl+F for search.